# Python read file without open and close on Linux

Tags: python

I'm trying to write a method that crops ton of images in a dataset.

```
def crop_20_percent(): #20% crop
    destination_dir_1 = "D:/Dataset/lab/crop_20_percent/"
    if os.path.exists(destination_dir_1) == False:
        os.mkdir(destination_dir_1)
    num_classes = 10
    # /home/json/Augmented_dataset/
    print("augmentation starts...")
    
    
    for i in range(num_classes):
        k=0
        t0 = time.time()
        t_mkd1 = time.time()
        os.mkdir(destination_dir_1 + str(i) + "/")
        t_mkd2 = time.time()
        print(t_mkd2-t_mkd1) 
        
        for address in glob.glob("D:/Dataset/lab/train_set/" + str(i) +"/*.jpg"):
            filename = os.path.basename(address)
            
            #PIL version
            image = Image.open(address) 
            width = image.size[0]
            height = image.size[1]
            channel = len(image.split())
            # print(width, height, channel)
            
            cropped_y_start = int((height * 0.9))
            cropped_y_end = int((height * 0.1))
            cropped_x_start = int((width * 0.9))
            cropped_x_end = int((width * 0.1))
            # print(cropped_y_start, cropped_y_end, cropped_x_start, cropped_x_end)
            
            crop_img = image.crop((cropped_x_end, cropped_y_start, cropped_x_start, cropped_y_end))
            t_open = time.time()
            f = open(destination_dir_1+str(i)+"/"+filename, 'w')
            image.save(destination_dir_1+str(i)+"/"+filename)
            f.close()
            t_close = time.time()
            print(t_close-t_open) 

            #print("image %s completed.." %k)
            k+=1
            t1 = time.time()
            time_record = round(t1-t0, 3)
            print(time_record) 
        print("class %s completed.." %i)
```

This code is working, but it takes way longer to complete the task on linux than windows. I checked the elapsed time and figured

```
t_open = time.time()
f = open(destination_dir_1+str(i)+"/"+filename, 'w')
image.save(destination_dir_1+str(i)+"/"+filename)
f.close()
t_close = time.time()
```

takes a lot of time.
Is there any way to run this method without using `.open` and `.close`? or are they must in linux?

Comment: It doesn't look like you're actually using the file object you opened. Why are you opening/closing it at all?

Comment: Do you know it's *actually* taking longer? Windows has very poor time stamp granularity for `time.time`, so it may tell you it took no time at all if it runs quickly enough, while Linux is likely to report a non-zero (but still small) value.